# Java Mobile Games Builder for Non-Programmers?

Tags: java, mobile

Is there any tool on the market that supports making games for mobile devices in Java, for non-programmers?

I need to find the best and fastest way to do that, before we plan to build such tool 
(for simple games only) as an add-on to our main product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a loot at [Game Builder](http://wiki.netbeans.org/CreatingJavaMEGamesWithGameBuilder).

Comment: i know it , its to much complicated also needs programming .
i mean something like : 
http://game-editor.com/